# Do I need to use dynamic_cast when calling a function that accepts the base class?

Tags: function, c++-cli, dynamic-cast

I have some classes like this:

```
interface class IA
{
};

interface class IB
{
};

public ref class C : public IA, public IB
{
};

public ref class D
{
    void DoSomething(IA^ aaa)
    {
    }

    void Run()
    {
        C^ bob = gcnew C();
        DoSomething(dynamic_cast<IA^>(bob));    // #1
        DoSomething(bob);           // #2
    }
};
```

At the moment I always try to use dynamic casting when calling such a function, (the #1 above).
However it does make the code quite ugly, so I want to know if it is actually necessary.

Do you use dynamic_cast in this way? If so what is the main reason?

Comment: Please note that C++ and C++-cli are very different beasts, so you might want to remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Done (although I assumed it would have the same behaviour...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know `bob` is of type `C^`, we know at compile time it can be downcasted to `IA^` safely, and so `dynamic_cast` is equivalent to `static_cast` here. Moreover, the implicit cast you propose is also safe.

`dynamic_cast` is only needed when upcasting from a base type to a derived.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C++, you use dynamic_cast to walk down the hierarchy, not up.  In this case, you'd use it to try and convert an IA or IB into a C:

```
IA^ temp = /* get a C in some way. */;
C^ tempC = dynamic_cast<C^>(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I would think that in C++/CLI you also don't need the dynamic cast here. Derived* implicitly converts to Base* unless there's an ambiguity w.r.t. multiple inheritance. The same it probably true for "gc-pointers". In C++ a dynamic cast -- when upcasting -- requires polymorphic classes (with at least one virtual function). I don't know how C++/CLI handles it, though. I would think every CLI class is by default polymorphic.

You may want to remove the C++ tag, by the way. ;)